# iterate through multiple lists of strings to find a common value

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to come up with something to find the substring 'angle' in each of these lists of strings:

```
ListA = ['angle 45', 'color red', 'inside t']

ListB = ['angle 135', 'color blue', 'inside f']

ListC = ['above r', 'angle 315', 'color pink', 'inside o']
```

I need to add a couple checks

1) only if 'angle' exists in all 3 lists

2) And if listA's 'angle' value does not equal listC's angle value,

Then get listC's angle value, subtract 90 and put the new string back in the list.
So, listC would now look like:

```
ListC = ['above r', 'angle 225', 'color red', 'inside r']
```

I've tried splitting these lists on white space to create lists like:

```
['angle', '45', 'color', 'red', 'inside', 't']
```

However, i'm having difficulty iterating through all 3 lists, then doing the subsequent checks, pulling a value and replacing. 
I'm wondering if I need to create a new dictionary or list to be able to fully implement this.

*Update*
This is what I have that checks for 'angle ' in all three lists then splits up each list further. What I haven't figured out is now that i've split angle from it's value, i'm not sure how I check that listA's angle value does not equal listB's. I haven't gotten to pulling the value, updating it and putting it back.

```
if any("angle " in s for s in listA) and any("angle " in s for s in listB) \
    and any("angle" in s for s in listC):
    listASplit = []
    for word in listA:
        word = word.split(" ")
        listASplit.extend(word)

    listBSplit = []
    for word in listB:
        word = word.split(" ")
        listBSplit.extend(word)

    listCSplit = []
    for word in listC:
        word = word.split(" ")
        listCSplit.extend(word)
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand the beginning. What output do you expect from each of your lists `ListA`, `ListB` and `ListC`. If I take `ListB` should the output be `['angle', '135', 'color', 'blue',  inside', 'f']`?

Comment: It's hard for us to understand the difficulty you're having without seeing your code and having a bit more explanation of the difficulty. Are you getting an error, or just incorrect results?

Comment: Some more sample code of what you're currently trying would be great—I think I understand what problem you're trying to solve, and I know a few ways to do it, however it's more helpful to you if we make suggestions to _improve_ your code rather than writing it for you.

Comment: Sure, I will post what I've been working on; I'm pretty sure it may be a horrible approach, that's why I was tentative to do that.

Comment: Some code is better than no code at all :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compartmentalize your work via functions:

```
def index_of_angle(lst):
    for string in lst:
        if string.startswith("angle"):
            return lst.index(string)
    # implicitly returns None if angle is not found

def get_angles(*lsts):
    return [index_of_angle(lst) for lst in lsts]
```

Now this is easy to follow:

```
a, b, c = get_angles(ListA, ListB, ListC)

if None not in [a, b, c]:  # Check 1 is obvious
    if ListA[a] != ListC[c]:  # Check 2 is obvious
        new_angle = int(ListC[c].split()[1]) - 90  # split by default is on spaces
        ListC[c] = "angle %d" % new_angle
```

To be even more explicit, you could rename `get_angles` to `get_angles_or_none` to make it clear it gives `None` if no angle is found.

---

To handle input where angle may appear more than once (and this input should be discarded):

```
def index_of_angle(lst):
    index_found = None
    for string in lst:
        if string.startswith("angle"):
            if index_found is not None:
                index_found = None  # if multiple angles found, set return to None
                break  # if two angles found, no need to keep looking
            index_found = lst.index(string)
    return index_found # returns angle or None if not found/multiple
```

This will be marginally slower, as we cannot return once we find angle (we must instead ensure that another angle entry does not exist first).

Comment: I've been putting off messing with functions, for way too long. This may be a good way to wrap my head around them. thank you sir

Comment: This is the code I have been working with. I've run into issues when 'angle' appears more than once in one of the original lists (A, B, C), is there a way to add another check that angle does not appear in any of this lists more than once?

Comment: I've edited the answer to include that change... essentially if you see more than one angle, treat it as no angle (invalid input).

Answer (score 3):

You've got a lot going on here, but I would agree that a dictionary would be better here.

To start with, let's parse the list

```
dictA = {}

for item in ListA:
    row = item.split(" ")
    dictA[row[0]] = row[1]
```

Do the same with each list, then you can compare values of the dictionaries without looping further.

```
if dictA['angle'] != to dictC['angle']:
    ...dostuff...
```

Don't forget to cast to the appropriate type when nessesary

Comment: far more elegant :) I concede that as a fact.

Comment: I appreciate it!

Comment: If you like an answer, don't forget to accept it :)

Comment: I'll probably accept yours since Swift concedes 'elegance' :) but I don't want to make any enemies. I appreciate all of your help.

Comment: No problem! Gotta start somewhere

Comment: A) `.split()` implicitly splits on whitespace, no need to specify. B) the first part could be simplified by using the builtin `dict`: `dictA = dict(row.split() for row in ListA)`

Comment: Pretty slick. Thanks!

Comment: Where do you account for angle being in all three here?

Comment: I don't. I thought the nature of the question was parsing the list into a format that such comparisons/checks would be easy and readable. Using the above method, any check can be done simply without looping further.

Answer (score 2):

```
lista = ['angle 45', 'color red', 'inside t'] 
listb = ['angle 135', 'color blue', 'inside f'] 
listc = ['above r', 'angle 315', 'color pink', 'inside o']
kw = 'angle'
results = []

for item in lista:
    if kw in item:
        results.append(item)
for item in listb:
    if kw in item:
        results.append(item)
for x in range(len(listc)):
    if kw in item[x]:
        results.append(item)
        index = x

if int(results[0].split()[1]) != int(results[2].split()[1]):
    lastindex = results[2].split()
    listc[index] = lastindex[0]+' '+str(int(lastindex[1])-90)
for x in results:
    print(x)
```

So explained:

I added a new variable called `kw` and this just hold the keyword we are searching for.

I also created an empty list called results to store the matches and their values.

When we iterate `listc` we iterate the range of the length of the list so that we can extract an index (to replace the string later).

So, we check all of the lists for the keyword and `append()` the match to `results`

After that, we check that the first and last values DO NOT match. If this is true, then we can split the string we extracted from `listc` and then minus 90 from the value before joining it back together and replacing the string in `listc`

Comment: Code only answer that doesn't actually address the question

Comment: I'm still writing it. Accidentally submitted :/

Comment: Haha I wont apologize for calling it how I see it, but it definitely looks a lot better now than it did :)

Comment: I dont really want an apology :P the upvote covers it :P

Comment: @krflol Apologize for what? He rushed a post then came back with a post that for the time being could have been more efficient, he should be using `enumerate` not  range len

Comment: Ok dude whatever you say. Are you watching my screen? I think that's illegal considering I'm currently in a private residence?

Comment: I did upvote because it is helpful, but I do think my answer is more elegant :P

Comment: I don't fully understand it yet, but i'm trying :) thank you! I appreciate the explanation, i'll give it a try

Comment: @yodish we all start somewhere :)

Comment: @swift “in fact, im almost certain my code beats your” meh pick battle and get upset , later bud, cheers ;)

Comment: Interesting views you have there. Don't mind if I continue watching this paint dry do you?

Answer (score 1):

```
def f(l):
    cnt  = 0
    for el in l:
        cnt+= len([x for x in el if 'angle' in x])
    if cnt == 3:
        if l[0][0] != l[1][0]:
            angle = l[2][1]
            n, d = angle.split()
            d = str(int(d) - 90)
            angle = n + " " + d
    l[2][1] = angle
    return l[2]

f([ListA, ListB, ListC])
```

['above r', 'angle 225', 'color pink', 'inside o']

Comment: this is blowing my mind a little but I may play around with this. Thank you!

Comment: While technically correct, I wouldn't want to maintain a codebase written like this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry I was at the Browns game, could have made your life easier sooner :)

```
listd = [lista, listb, listc]

if 'angle' in ''.join(lista) and ''.join(listb) and ''.join(listc):
    for idx, item, in enumerate(lista):
        for x, i in enumerate(listc):
            if 'angle' in item and 'angle' in i:
                if item.split()[1] != i.split()[1]:
                    listc[x] = i.split()[0] + ' ' + str(int(i.split()[1]) - 90)

print(listd)
```

> ```
> [['angle 45', 'color red', 'inside t'], ['angle 135', 'color blue',
> 'inside f'], ['above r', 'angle 225', 'color pink', 'inside o']]
> ```

Comment: @swift 16 lines v 6 lines, “in fact, im almost certain my code beats your code” , your cute <3

Comment: @yodish no need to remake new lists no dictionary creating just your data and 6 lines bud <3 sorry was in Cleveland or would have rescued you from these repsonses sooner

Comment: thanks man. I've got a lot of good solutions to work with now.

Comment: @yodish no prop took this one personal ha wanted something clean, no modifications to your code or altering just plug n play, have fun

Comment: You were rooting *against* the Browns, right? :) (former steel city guy, before relocating)

Comment: haha I'm more a mma/boxing guy I but my bro-in-law is browns season ticket holder, insane game first NFL game ever and they break a 2 year losing streak at home during primetime game O.o